# GeoIP Routing with Windows Azure

Tags: azure, geolocation, geo, ip-geolocation

I'm working on a somewhat large project that will eventually be loaded on Azure.  The idea is we will have multiple compute nodes all over the world as our customer base is potentially that large.  The question I have is this:

If I have nodes in the US, Europe, Asia, etc. for DR and load balancing reasons how can I combine the idea of Geo-based DNS results with Azure since our application will simply be a CNAME for our URL?

I'm not sure I quite understand the deployment strategy for one application running out of multiple regions with Azure.  Does anyone have any links or references to better understand the model?

Mod Note: Not sure if this should be ServerFault but I thought StackOverflow was a better location.

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [Windows Azure Traffic Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_WindowsAzureTrafficManager) it allows you to group deployments across regions as one logical service and automatically routes a request to the nearest region.

Comment: Perfect, I looked at this last night but I guess I totally glossed over the entire "performance" section.  Thanks!